# Align div with 2 images left side near table that is centered

Tags: css

I have 4 centered tables (header, navigation, content, footer):

```
<table id="header" width="760" align="center">...</table>
<table id="navigation" width="760" align="center">...</table>

<table width="760" height="28" border="0" align="center" id="content">
    ...
</table>

<table id="footer" width="760" align="center">...</table>
```

I have removed some code from above example (borders, cellpadding etc.)
This makes tables to be in the center of the screen and with width=760.
In this case left and right margins of the screen contains some white spaces.
I need to put 4 images in those white spaces (two images on the left side of the table; images are to be positioned vertically; and two images on the right side - also positioned one on top of the other image).

So, probably I need to create two divs (Left div and Right div).
And I need those Divs to be aligned to the left side of all tables and to the right side of all tables.

LEFT DIV|ALL TABLES| RIGHT DIV

Images have max allowed width, but they do not have any predefined height.

I do not know how to do this... 
I usually do backend, so I do not need CSS much. But not in this project... Usually I do not use Tables but Divs for layout and then I would use position="relative" for Left and Right Divs, but it seems that it would not work with tables.

Can you give me some clues, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got to wrapp your tables in a div. take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jt46m/5/). you can adjust the css for you own likings but that is how you do what you want.

**EDIT**
added clearfix instead of `overflow: hidden;`, and added two images on each side.
**EDIT2** here is how to make layout centred. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jt46m/6/)

```
<div id="wrapper clearfix">
  <div class="side-div">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff.png" alt="left" />
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff.png" alt="left" />
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
    tables
  </div>

  <div class="side-div">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff.png" alt="right" />
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff.png" alt="right" />
  </div>
</div>​



.side-div {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-content {
    float: left;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccddff;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/*clearfix instead of overflow: hidden;*/

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

​

Comment: Is not it possible to do this without wrapping table into div? Unfourtunately given website doesn't have centralized layout and I really do not want to change every page of website wrapping table into div :(.

Comment: Not really, but does it matter, you still need to add the divs with the images to the pages right? One question what does centralized layout has to do with my example? And do you work with php or .net?

Comment: I tried your sollution (for one page) and it works with divs, but centralized layout disappears. Table should be aligned in the center of the screen. Now it is not. I am using ASP (classic ASP). And it is not designed with "masterpage" concept or similar. For adding img divs I will create Function and it is not so difficult to add "call func1" and "call func2" in every page, however, it would be painfull to do any other layout changes in every page.

Comment: I just edited my answer for you centred layout. How many pages are we talking about 10 or 100's?

Comment: add `text-align: center;` to the wrapper and it will be fixed

Comment: it still doesn't work in IE. It doesn't create centered layout, but left justified.

Comment: im sorry i mean the html, body should have text-align center

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot get it working in IE. Please, see here - http://www.haozeret.co.il/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21996/discussion-between-dejan-s-and-renathy)